# I cannot get the body data from JSONP's response with Angular2, but it works by using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angular, jsonp

First, I coded the **SERVER** using spring-boot, code like these:

```
public class App {
@RequestMapping("/")
@ResponseBody
String home(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String aa=request.getParameter("callback");
    System.out.println(request.getParameter("callback"));
    return aa+"({\"text\":\"hello,world\"})";
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
}}
```

Second, I coded the **FRONT-END** with Angular2:

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit{
  constructor(private jsonp:Jsonp) {
      }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.jsonp.get("http://localhost:8080/callback=JSONP_CALLBACK")
      .subscribe(res=>console.log(this.res);    
  );    
}}
```

then, I run the front-end in ng-serve, and got the infomation from console:

```
Response {_body: Object, status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "Ok", headers: Headers…}
```

obviously, the "_body: Object" has the data I want, and in actual, the data looks like:

```
{"text":"hello,world"}
```

so i tried to get the data, but Observable's operator "subscribe" only has these method:
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWSwO.png)

so i selected the json method, but i got these from console:

```
function () {
        if (typeof this._body === 'string') {
            return JSON.parse(/** @type {?} */ (this._body));
        }
        if (this._body instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
            return …
```

I had tried every method, but cannot get the body data, except this weird approach:

```
console.log(res._body.text);
```

of course, it has compile error, but I do get the data:[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tcixq.png)

All the problems above are not appeared when I tried this by using AJAX, I can easily get the data like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    $.ajax({
         type: "get",
         async: false,
         url: "http://localhost:8080/",
         dataType: "jsonp",
         jsonp: "callback",
         jsonpCallback:"JSONP_CALLBACK",
         success: function(json){
             console.log(json.text);
         },
         error: function(){
             alert('fail');
         }
     });
 });
```

So, how can I get the json data with rxjs's Observable in Angular2, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to map response as JSON:

```
this.jsonp.get("http://localhost:8080/callback=JSONP_CALLBACK")
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: oh, dear! thanks, so so much~~but why I cannot do the "res.json()" in the subscribe?

Comment: you can: `.subscribe(res => console.log(res.json()));` but it's cleaner to send final data to subscribe and process it on previous step. Usually it's better to keep all data loading logic in services. which return Observable instances. Then in components you simple call service method and subscribe to whatever data it provides. So you don't want to process data in component, instead you want to consume it. But in your case you have this call in component anyway, so you can of course just skip extra map step and just use `res.json()` in subscribe directly.

Comment: uh...I know why i cannot do the" res.json()", cuz i missed the "()", T T....SO STUPID. thanks again~~